# Says I'm missing 1 position argument (a spotipy object) Flask

Tags: python, http, web, flask, spotipy

Working with flask to make a website. After I get user input using POST I need to send the retrieved info to another function.

Getting Error that says:

```
TypeError: search() missing 1 required positional argument: 'spotifyObj'
```

Here is the code I think that is causing it:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def home(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret, redirect_uri=redirect_uri, scope=scope):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.form["username"]

        token = util.prompt_for_user_token(user, scope, client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri)
        obj = createObj(token)

        searchType = request.form["searchType"]

        return redirect(url_for("search", searchT=searchType, spotifyObj=obj))
    else:
        return render_template("home.html")

@app.route("/<searchT>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def search(searchT,spotifyObj):
```

I don't understand what the problem is. Also this is my first time ever developing a website so sorry if there are a bunch of major newbie mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is below.
You have a method named `search`.

The method is expecting to get 2 arguments:

- searchT
- spotifyObj

> ```
> @app.route("/<searchT>", methods=["POST", "GET"])  
>     def search(searchT,spotifyObj)
> ```

The Flask decorator `app.route` is passing only one argument to the method.

You have two options:

- change the method signature and make it accept 1 argument
- change the `/<searchT>` inside the decorator and make sure it will pass 2 arguments

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I tried the second option but it does not work I think because obj is not a string. Is there anyway to pass objects via this way?

Comment: No. There is no way. You can only pass simple variable like str or int

Comment: You can call search directly ( without redirect ), get a result and use it in 'home'